# How to do a Kafka Streams Left Join that returns LHS messages that have no corresponding RHS after a fixed period?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm new to Kafka Streams.  I've just put together a left join between Stream A and Stream B.  It happens in my setup that for every A there is a B, which arrives a few millis after A but in real life there may be missing B's, or B's that arrive late (after say 250ms). I want to be able to find these (missing and late B's).
I thought it would be easy - just do a left join between A and B, specify the window, and job done.
But I found to my surprise that I get 2 rows in the left join stream output.
Thinking about it, this makes sense - when A arrives, there is no B and a join row that looks like `A-[null]` is generated. A few milliseconds later, B arrives, and then `A-B` is generated.

What I want is to have those A messages that do not have a corresponding B after say 100ms - B could be late; might never arrive; but it did not arrive within 100ms of A.
Is there a standard pattern / idiomatic way to do this?  I am thinking at the moment that maybe I would have to have a consumer that receives the A and then fires a message after a set time (although I'm not exactly sure how that would be done without some clunky synchronous code) and then I would have to join between that (call it Ax) and B.

This is probably quite a common requirement, but it doesn't seem as easy as I first thought....any thoughts/pointers/tips would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK I have something that seems to work.  All I need to do is, after the left join (which of course has a window), do a `.groupByKey().count()` and after that I can e.g. send stuff (using `filter()` and `branch()` I think, although I haven't done it yet) with a count < 2 to one stream ("missing"), and the others to another "good" stream eg for analysis/calculation of metrics etc.

I tried using `.windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(ofMillis(250)).grace(ofMillis(10)))`
and `.suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(unbounded()));` but got nowhere with it, so it's just as well that a groupBy with count is all that is needed by the looks of things.